# RTCDataChannel ready state stuck at connecting in chrome but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I am trying to implement [RTCDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/readyState)(webRTC).

It's working good in Firefox but not in chrome.

Both Chrome and Firefox are of the latest version.

RTCDataChannel object in Chrome :-

```
RTCDataChannel {
binaryType: "arraybuffer"
bufferedAmount: 0
bufferedAmountLowThreshold: 0
id: 65535
label: "sendDataChannel"
maxRetransmitTime: 65535
maxRetransmits: 65535
negotiated: false
onbufferedamountlow: null
onclose: null
onerror: ƒ (event)
onmessage: ƒ (event)
onopen: ƒ dataChannelStateChanged()
ordered: true
protocol: ""
readyState: "connecting"
reliable: false__proto__:}
```

RTCDataChannel object in Firefox :-

```
DataChannel { 
binaryType: "blob"
id: 0
label: "sendDataChannel", 
reliable: true, 
readyState: "open",
bufferedAmount: 0, 
bufferedAmountLowThreshold: 0, 
onopen: dataChannelStateChanged(), 
onerror: create_peer_connection/dataChannel.onerror(), 
onclose: null, 
onmessage: create_peer_connection/dataChannel.onmessage(), 
onbufferedamountlow: null 
protocol:""
ordered:true}
```

I have already gone through below links:-

1. [WebRTC data channel stack on readyState "conecting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244468/webrtc-data-channel-stack-on-readystate-conecting)
2. [WebRTC dataChannel.readyState stalling on "connecting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104933/webrtc-datachannel-readystate-stalling-on-connecting)
3. [RTCDataChannel's ReadyState is not 'open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470291/rtcdatachannels-readystate-is-not-open).
4. [Webrtc Data Channel always in connecting state and not open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769713/webrtc-data-channel-always-in-connecting-state-and-not-open)

Please suggest what could be the reason behind the issue in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve it using the following post :

[WebRTC DataChannel: working in Firefox but not Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333900/webrtc-datachannel-working-in-firefox-but-not-chrome?rq=1)

I had to change

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration,
                {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
```

to

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```